# Where is the correct place to put utility functions for a JQuery plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Lets say I have a jQuery plugin I have created like this ([from the jquery site](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)):

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white"
        }, options );

        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        return this.css({
            color: settings.color,
            backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

But now maybe I need a number of larger functions to facilitate my plugin operation, where is the best place to put these functions and keep my code neat, readable and testable?

For example I think localized functions would be a bad idea, like this:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

        // This would be bad becase too many of these and my code will be clutered.
        var aHelperFunctionThatIsHuge = function () {
          // A lot of code here...
        };

        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white"
        }, options );

        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        return this.css({
            color: settings.color,
            backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

This doesn't work at all:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

        // This is the easiest way to have default options.
        var settings = $.extend({
            // These are the defaults.
            color: "#556b2f",
            backgroundColor: "white"
        }, options );

        // Greenify the collection based on the settings variable.
        return this.css({
            color: settings.color,
            backgroundColor: settings.backgroundColor
        });

    };

    // ideal but doesnt work
    $.fn.greenify.aHelperFunctionThatIsHuge = function () {
          // A lot of code here...
    };


}( jQuery ));
```

So where should I put them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above the plugin function, inside the IIFE:

```
(function ( $ ) {

    var aHelperFunctionThatIsHuge = function () {
      // A lot of code here...
    };

    $.fn.greenify = function( options ) {

    };

}( jQuery ));
```

Comment: isnt that then scoped to the entire $ scope? I don't want those functions available outside of the plugin itself?

Comment: No, `(function ( $ ) { ... }( jQuery ));` creates a new scope and only functions defined inside of it can access the local variables declared there. `$` is not a scope, it's rather a namespace. Only elements you explicitly add to the namespace can be accessed outside the IIFE.